# Instance variable definition disappearing after a method().call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two activejobs, one calls the other. The first active job finishes and calls the second active job providing with it a method to complete after perform. I have run a debugger and found that everything before the method('ending_method').call returns the helpers just find. After the method.call, only the first helper returns correctly, the second helper returns nil but if I do a manual first_helper.attribute, the value is returned. Why is this?? I figure it has something to do with variable scoping but since it is inconsistent, that confuses me.

active job 1:

```
class FirstJob < ApplicationJob
include Helper
queue_as :default

before_perform do |obj|
    first_helper(obj.arguments.first)
end

def perform(model_id,length)
    code....
    other_method
end

def other_method
    second_helper ----> works fine
end
```

active job 2:

```
class SecondJob < ApplicationJob
include Helper
queue_as :default

before_perform do |obj|
    first_helper(obj.arguments.first)
end

def perform(model_id,ending_method)
    code....
    method(ending_method).call
end

def ending_method
    second_helper ----> variable is nil
end
```

Helper:

```
module Helper

def first_helper(*id_string)
    return @first_helper if defined?(@first_helper)
    @first_helper = Model.find_by(model_id: id_string)
end

def second_helper
    return @second_helper if defined?(@second_helper)
    @second_helper = first_helper.attribute
end
```

Comment: Is the `before_perform` in `SecondJob` supposed to be calling `first_helper` instead? And is `helper_method` in `FirstJob` also supposed to be doing the same thing?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo... they both call the same thing first_helper. I will correct it now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after process of elimination, it had nothing to do with the method().call. The issue is below. The code inside the 'if' statement (despite being false and never parsed) was overwriting the second_helper variable to nil. I realized that I should not be doing this anyway after the fact because I am not setting the object attribute but rather a variable. Not sure why this showed up this way... very strange to me.

```
if (false)
  second_helper += 1
end

def second_helper
  return @second_helper if defined?(@second_helper)
  @second_helper = first_helper.attribute
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an actual answer. You clarify things (which is good!) but you also raise more questions. Maybe you should update the origional question instead.